# Using Pandas str.contains using Case insensitive

Tags: python, dataframe

My Dataframe:

```
Req Col1
1   Apple is a fruit
2   Sam is having an apple
3   Orange is orange
```

I am trying to create a new df having data related to apple only.

My code:

```
Apple=df1[df1.col1.str.contains('apple',case=False)]
```

It is not helping to get the correct output. Also, I don't want to change the complete col1 tolower()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work for me the only problem I found was that you are selecting `col1` instead of `Col1`. The following code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Req': [1,2,3],
                    'Col1': ['Apple is a fruit',
                             'Sam is having an apple',
                             'Orange is orange']})
Apple=df1[df1.Col1.str.contains('apple',case=False)]
print(Apple)
```

prints

```
>>>    Req                    Col1
>>> 0    1        Apple is a fruit
>>> 1    2  Sam is having an apple
```